# Add confirm Popup

Tags: javascript

I have this code in line:

```
$action = "window.location = 'fruit_list.php.php?do=delete&id={$fruitdata['id']}";
echo '<a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="javascript:' . $action . '">Delete</a>';?>
```

Is there a way to add below code to make confirm box popup when link clicked?

```
 onclick="return confirm('are you sure?')"
```

Comment: Why you don't use `href` ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add return to the onclick, just

`<a href='#' onclick='confirm("Are you sure?")'> Click </a>`

http://jsfiddle.net/PFKFq/1/

Comment: I would like to combine two code as I posted above. (Link Hide in browser bar)

Answer (score 0):

```
$action = "if(window.event) event=window.event; event.preventDefault();if (confirm('Are you sure?')){window.location = 'fruit_list.php.php?do=delete&id={$fruitdata['id']} }";
echo '<a style="cursor: pointer" onclick="javascript:' . $action . '">Delete</a>';?>
```

Comment: For a tags, you should preventDefault action that takes you to another page. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: @user2277739: well, in the past, I did not know that I had to mention the user name so that you can get the message. Maybe It's too late.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `href` ?

```
<?php
$link = "fruit_list.php?do=delete&id={$fruitdata['id']}";
echo "<a href='{$link}' onclick='return confirm(\"Delete ?\");'>Delete</a>";
```